# What is the best way to get the last inserted auto-generated ID using slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using Slick (Scala) for my project. My problem is how to retrieve the last inserted ID using the lifted embedding API. The ID is auto-incremented. I have read the documentation, but I'm afraid I didn't understand it well enough. Can you provide a more detailed explanation and sample code about how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [the Slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#inserting) you can use the `returning <Table>.id` variant.

Suppose you have a cat defined in a slickish manner:

```
case class Cat(id: Option[Int], name: String)
object Cats extends Table[Cat]("cats") {
  def id = column[Int]("cat_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = id.? ~ name <> (Cat.apply _, Cat.unapply _)
}
```

Then you can receive a newly created `id` within the moment you insert a new cat.

```
val newCatId =
  Cats returning Cats.id insert Cat(None, "Cringer")
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: when insertion fails it should throw the error that caused the failure